# Adjust position of tick marks in ggplot faceted barplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a dataset split into 20 groups (strictly 2 groups with 10 iterations each), 1-10 A and B.
Each group has some features that are correlated with dimensions 1-5. So e.g. in group 1A, feature X and Y correlate with dimension 1, and features Z and Q with dimension 3, but in group 2A only feature X correlates with dimension 1 and feature Z and Y correlate with dimension 2.

ETA: the dput output, sorry, not done this before!

```
structure(list(group = structure(c(2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 2L, 2L, 2L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), iteration = structure(c(10L, 
4L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 
6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 
10L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 5L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 6L, 
6L, 9L, 1L, 10L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 1L, 
10L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 
7L, 8L, 9L, 9L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 9L, 2L, 3L, 5L), .Label = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor"), 
    `group name` = c("B10", "B4", "A10", "A3", "A3", "A4", "A5", 
    "A6", "A7", "A8", "A9", "B10", "B2", "B4", "B5", "B5", "B6", 
    "B7", "B8", "B9", "A10", "A2", "A2", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", 
    "A8", "A9", "B1", "B1", "B10", "B10", "B2", "B3", "B5", "B7", 
    "B8", "B9", "A1", "A10", "A10", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A6", "A6", 
    "A9", "B1", "B10", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", 
    "B8", "B9", "A1", "A1", "A10", "A2", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", 
    "A7", "A8", "A9", "B1", "B2", "B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B7", 
    "B8", "B9", "B9", "A1", "A3", "A4", "A5", "A6", "A7", "A8", 
    "A9", "B2", "B3", "B5"), feature = c("AR", "AR", "f0", "f0", 
    "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", 
    "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f0", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", 
    "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", 
    "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f1", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", 
    "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", 
    "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f2", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", 
    "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", 
    "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f3", "f4", "f4", "f4", "f4", 
    "f4", "f4", "f4", "f4", "f4", "f4", "f4"), measure = c("AR mean global", 
    "AR mean global", "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", 
    "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", 
    "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", 
    "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", 
    "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", 
    "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", "f0 mean short term", 
    "f0 mean short term", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", 
    "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", 
    "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", 
    "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f1 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", 
    "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", 
    "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", 
    "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f2 mean", "f3 mean", 
    "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", 
    "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", 
    "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f3 mean", 
    "f3 mean", "f3 mean", "f4 mean", "f4 mean", "f4 mean", "f4 mean", 
    "f4 mean", "f4 mean", "f4 mean", "f4 mean", "f4 mean", "f4 mean", 
    "f4 mean"), score = c(0.555, 0.521, 0.782, 0.561, 0.534, 
    0.539, 0.539, 0.552, 0.768, 0.768, 0.607, 0.581, 0.584, 0.529, 
    0.546, 0.52, 0.583, 0.523, 0.559, 0.627, 0.55, 0.587, 0.56, 
    0.581, 0.582, 0.558, 0.623, 0.623, 0.62, 0.635, 0.516, 0.517, 
    0.571, 0.603, 0.609, 0.522, 0.617, 0.544, 0.543, 0.751, 0.604, 
    0.546, 0.518, 0.686, 0.665, 0.56, 0.663, 0.566, 0.626, 0.608, 
    0.61, 0.577, 0.652, 0.677, 0.667, 0.553, 0.588, 0.62, 0.722, 
    0.586, 0.539, 0.615, 0.602, 0.619, 0.694, 0.528, 0.814, 0.654, 
    0.654, 0.551, 0.699, 0.609, 0.541, 0.688, 0.546, 0.686, 0.695, 
    0.532, 0.517, 0.528, 0.615, 0.516, 0.672, 0.521, 0.547, 0.584, 
    0.584, 0.595, 0.598, 0.591, 0.528), dimension = structure(c(5L, 
    4L, 4L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 5L, 5L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 3L, 
    2L, 3L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 
    1L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    2L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 3L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 2L, 3L, 2L
    ), .Label = c("dim1", "dim2", "dim3", "dim4", "dim5"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-91L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I've plotted each of these groups and their correlations in barplots, but as you can see in the image linked below, the axis tick for each dimension is really weirdly aligned. I don't understand how they're spaced. I would ideally like an axis tick centred for each set of bars for that dimension, or failing that a separate axis tick for each bar.

Here's the code i've tried:

```
ggplot(data=corr, aes(x=dimension, y=score)) + 
  geom_col(aes(fill=feature),width=4,position=position_dodge2(width=1, 
            preserve=c('total')), na.rm=TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(`iteration`~`group`, scales="free_x",nrow=5) +
  labs(x="Dimension", y="Correlation Coefficient (Abs. value)")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[here's the barplot that comes from that code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vo8xq.png)

Adding scale_x_discrete with breaks named has not helped. At this point I have been dipping in and out of working on this since before Christmas so I'm not sure of everything I've tried, but would appreciate the help!

Comment: Please copy/paste the results of `dput(corr)` so we can reproduce your results.

Comment: As John says, please paste `dput` output. However, I have had a similar problem and it was due the `position` parameter. In this case both `x` and `position` are trying to control the position of bars on the x axis, whilst only `x` controls the position of the labels. It is hard to give a fix without the data but one quick trick is first to try without a position argument, and then to try with just `position = "dodge"`

Comment: Thanks both, have edited to add - new to this sorry.
Tried with just 'position=dodge'. Bars were overlapping but changed the width to help this. However I want all the bars to be the same width which is what 'preserve=c('total')' was achieving in the original code. Can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The tick marks look to not be in the right place due to the very large width you have set to your columns (`geom_col(... width=4...)`).  The result is due to columns overlapping into the other dimensions on your x axis combined with the attempt of `position_dodge2()` to prevent this.

TL;DR - change the `width=` arguments to something that makes the plot more viewable, yet you will still have unequal column widths across facets (since `preserve=` does not work across facets).

You can much more easily see the separation and how the tickmarks should appear with your data if you lower the `width=` argument for `geom_col()` and also `position_dodge2(width=`).  Ultimately, the width of each individual column is a result of a combination of these two `width=` arguments.  Think of it this way:

- Setting `width=...` in `geom_col()` controls the width of the bar across the entire x dimension value.  If you have one bar, it's the bar's width.  If you have two bars (dodged), then this represents the combined width of both bars.  For discrete x values, you can consider `1` to represent the entire width of one value.
- Setting `width=...` in `position_dodge2()` controls how far apart the dodged bars are spaced.  The bars are centered at the given x value, but they are spaced such that the width of the spacing between them (the distance between their middles) is equal to `width`.

Normally, this means that if you set `width=4` and `position_dodge2(width=1)` you would expect the bars to be *heavily* overlapping, but `position_dodge2()` has some special adjustments that prevent overlap.  In this case, the bars would just be pushed up against each other with some buffer in-between.  This gets really messed up when you start using `preserve=`... and it's a bit too detailed to explain here.

The simplest fix to make your plot look better and be readable is to set the `width=` and `position_dodge2(width=...)` to more reasonable values.  This will allow for the viewer to actually see what's going on.  This seemed to work pretty well:

```
ggplot(data=corr, aes(x=dimension, y=score)) +
  geom_col(aes(fill=feature),width=0.8,position=position_dodge2(width=0.8,
                                                              preserve=c('single')), na.rm=TRUE) +
  facet_wrap(`iteration`~`group`, scales="free_x",nrow=5) +
  labs(x="Dimension", y="Correlation Coefficient (Abs. value)")+
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(hjust=0.5))
```

[image]

You'll notice that not all the bars are the same width... that is unfortunately basically a bug with the `position_dodge()` functions.  It seems the `preserve=` argument only applies **in each facet** separately, and not across all facets.  I'm not sure at the moment if there's a fix for that.